# Dual Spaces and injectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

If T is a linear mapping $V \rightarrow W$ , And $T'g$ is defined as the composition $g(T(x))$ where $g$ is a linear form on W, then I want to show that if $T$ is surjective then $T'g$ is injective. This problem has me totally stumped.

Thoughts: I know that for a linear mapping that if the kernel is the zero vector then it is injective, so is this essentially saying that if no matter what the input, the output of g(T(x)) is 0 then g must be the zero function?

Comment: Yes. If $g(T(x))$ is $0$ everywhere on $V$ and $T$ is surjective, then $g(x)$ is $0$ everywhere on $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is surjective.

Assume that $g \in W^*$ and $g\neq 0$. Pick a vector $w\in W$ such that $g(w) \neq 0$. Since $T$ is surjective we can choose $v \in V$ with $Tv=w$. Then $(T'g)(v) = g(T(v))=g(w) \neq 0$, and thus $T'g \neq 0$.

So, we showed that if $T$ is surjective then $g \neq 0$ implies $T'g \neq 0$, i.e, $T'$ is injective.